# How to use preg_match to extract data?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am pretty new to the use of preg_match. Searched a lot for an answer before posting this question. Found a lot of posts to get data based on youtube ID etc. But nothing as per my needs. If its silly question, please forgive me.

I need to get the ID from a string with preg_match. the string is in the format

```
[#1234] Subject
```

How can I extract only "1234" from the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is:

```
\[#(\d+)\]
```

This matches the left square bracket and pound sign `[#`, then captures one or more digits, then the closing right square bracket `]`.

You would use it like:

```
preg_match( '/\[#(\d+)\]/', '[#1234] Subject', $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // 1234
```

You can see it working in [this demo](http://3v4l.org/mq1Go).

Comment: It is not working if there is any prefix for the ID like Re : [#1234] Subject

Comment: @Mic - That wasn't in your original post, but it's easily fixed by removing the `^` from the regex. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I am sorry, if my question created a confusion.

Comment: @Mic - Not a problem, I've updated my answer, please try again!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
preg_match('~(?<=\[#)\d+(?=])~', $txt, $match);
```

`(?<=..)` is a lookbehind (only a check)

`(?=..)` is a lookahead

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression:

```
preg_match('/^\[\#([0-9]+)\].+/i', $string, $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a way you could do it:

```
<?php
$subject = "[#1234] Subject";
$pattern = '/^\[\#([0-9]+)/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);

echo $matches[1]; // 1234
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get only the integer you can use subpatterns  http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php

```
 $string="[#1234] Subject";
 $pattern="/\[#(?P<my_id>\d+)](.*?)/s";
 preg_match($pattern,$string,$match);
 echo $match['my_id'];
```