# Extracting data using hash sign in preg_match_all() pattern does not work

Tags: php, regex

I am new to RegEx. I am parsing a HTML page and because it is buggy I cannot use a XML or HTML parser. So I am using a regular expression.
My code looks like this:

```
$html = '<html><div data-id="ABC012" data-index="123" ...';
preg_match_all('/<div data-id="[A-Z\\d]+" data-index="\\d+"/', $html, $result);
var_dump($result);
```

The output looks good so the code is working. Now I want to extract the matched values. I did it exactly as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18035550/11016652) answer and now the code looks like this:

```
$html = '<html><div data-id="ABC012" data-index="123" ...';
preg_match_all('/<div data-id="#([A-Z\\d]+)" data-index="#(\\d+)"/', $html, $result);
var_dump($result);
```

But it outputs an empty array. What is wrong? Please don't improve the pattern by adding the closing '>' or making it robust against white spaces. I just need to get the code running.

Comment: `"because it is buggy I cannot use a XML or HTML parser."` - have you set `libxml` options for ignoring errors?

Comment: `()` returns the matched results. `#` does nothing, remove them.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I am not sure but one problem was that the PHP XML parser did not understand HTML self closing tags. For example it's normal to never close <br> tags in HTML.

Comment: @Foobar Oops I thought the hash tags was neccessary to extract data. It's working now...

Comment: I've not had issue with `DOMDocument` or `DOMXPath` to parse many HTML pages after setting the `libxml` parameters to ignore errors - I don't believe that a self-closing `br` tag (ie: `<br />` ) would cause any problems at all

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius "<br/>" is not a self closing tag. "<br>" is.

Comment: `<br>` will not cause issue either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write the code and the pattern like this, using a single backslash to match digits `\d` and omit the `#` in the pattern as that is not in the example data:

```
$html = '<html><div data-id="ABC012" data-index="123" ...';
preg_match_all('/<div data-id="([A-Z\d]+)" data-index="(\d+)"/', $html, $result);
var_dump($result);
```

Output

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(38) "<div data-id="ABC012" data-index="123""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "ABC012"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "123"
  }
}
```